# Allow only onward date and block backward date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

How I will restrict a user to enter only max date of the previous entered date?
I want to enter only onward date and block backward date in SQL and c#.net in windowform?
In the blow image textbox "Auto Most Recent Date (Last Date)" is backward date and textbox "Enter Next Date" is onward date.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to limit the max date like that? Why does it matter if they put a value in the future?

Comment: Just Date sir... e.g. if date. 20-05-2021 has been entered in db then I want to enter only 21-05-2021 date. I want to restrict 19-05-2021 date before insertion of a record.

Comment: Sir I want to restrict a user from backward entry not from next date/future date...

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The reason I ask is that _one day_ someone is going to put the date wrong (often around the start of a new year). And this kind of rule is going to bite you in the arse hard. Since not only will that date be wrong _no-one else will be able to enter any data_ (perhaps for another year!). What _actual_ problem is this trying to solve?

Comment: If you want to enter only future dates you need to set a Min date of X, not a Max one

Answer (score 3):

You clearly know how to query a database, so run a query like:

```
SELECT MAX(somedate) FROM courtcases WHERE casenumber = @whatever
```

And use the output of it on your date time picker

```
nextDateDateTimePicker.MinDate = <the DateTime you queried>
```

If the min date is a day later, use AddDays(1) on the date you queried

(Not that that looks like a standard win forms datetimepicker but I’m sure whatever you’re using will have a similar facility)

I don’t think you need to go to the extent of protecting your insert sql against hacking to ensure the user hasn’t modified the ui in some way and put an illegal date in